# Shadertoy - fragCoord vs iResolution vs fragColor

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, shadertoy

I'm fairly new to Shadertoy and GLSL in general.  I have successfully duplicated numerous Shadertoy shaders into Blender without actually knowing how it all works.  I have looked for tutorials but I'm more of a visual learner.

If someone could explain or, even better, provide some images that describe the difference between fragCoord, iResolution, & fragColor. That would be great!

I'm mainly interested in the Numbers. Because I use Blender I'm used to the canvas being 0 to 1 -or- -1 to 1

This one in particular has me a bit confused.

```
vec2 u = (fragCoord - iResolution.xy * .5) / iResolution.y * 8.;
```

[image: example]

I can't reproduce the remaining code in Blender without knowing the coordinate system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: learning question, What do you mean with: "I have successfully duplicated numerous Shadertoy shaders into Blender". In Blender OSL, or the Blender 2.8 PyGL interface, or by visually match the output ?

Comment: @nabr In Blender 2.8 using Cycles Nodes. I had to create numerous vector math groups due to how glsl does their math.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is normal, you cannot reproduce this code in blender without knowing the coordinate system.

[The Shadertoy documentation states:](https://www.shadertoy.com/howto)

> Image shaders implement the mainImage() function to generate
> procedural images by calculating a color for each pixel in the image.
> This function is invoked once in each pixel and the host application
> must provide the appropriate input data and retrieve the output color
> to assign it to the corresponding pixel on the screen. The signature
> of this function is:
>
> void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord);
>
> where fragCoord contains the coordinates of the pixel for which the
> shader must calculate a color. These coordinates are counted in pixels
> with values from 0.5 to resolution-0.5 over the entire rendering
> surface and the resolution of this surface is transmitted to the
> shader via the uniform iResolution variable.

Let me explain.

The `iResolution` variable is a `uniform vec3` which contains the dimensions of the window and is sent to the shader with some openGL code.

The `fragCoord` variable is a built-in variable that contains the coordinates of the pixel where the shader is being applied.

More concretely:

- **fragCoord** : is a `vec2` that is between 0 > 640 on the X axis and 0 > 360 on the Y axis
- **iResolution** : is a `vec2` with an X value of 640 and a Y value of 360

quick note on how vectors work in OpenGL:

- if you have also a hard time understanging how vector work in OpenGL, I highly recommand to read the anwser of Homan bellow, a very usefull introduction to OpenGL swizzling.

---

[image: Standard normalize uv]

This image was calculated with the following code:

```
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (between 0 and 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    // Set R and G values based on position
    vec3 col = vec3(uv.x,uv.y,0);

    // Output to screen
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
```

The output ranges from `0,0` in the lower-left and `1,1` in the upper-right. This is the default lower-left windows space set by OpenGL.

---

[image: Windows centred uv]
This an image was calculated with the following code:

```
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (between -0.5 and 0.5)
    vec2 uv = (fragCoord - iResolution.xy * 0.5)/iResolution.xy;
    
    // Set R and G values based on position
    vec3 col = vec3(uv.x,uv.y,0);

    // Output to screen
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
```

The output ranges from `-0.5,-0.5` in the lower-left and `0.5,0.5` because
in the first step we subtract half of the window size [`0.5`] from each pixel coordinate [`fragCoord`]. You can see the effect in the way the red and green values don't kick into visibility until much later.

You might also want to normalize **only** the y axis by changing the first step to

```
vec2 uv = (fragCoord - iResolution.xy * 0.5)/iResolution.y;
```

Depending our your purpose the image can seem strange if you normalize both axes so this is a possible strategy.

---

[image: ceil() uv to see more clearly]

This an image was calculated with the following code:

```
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (between -0.5 to 0.5)
    vec2 uv = (fragCoord - iResolution.xy * 0.5)/iResolution.xy;
   
    // Set R and G values based on position using ceil() function
    // The ceil() function returns the smallest integer that is greater than the uv value
    vec3 col = vec3(ceil(uv.x),ceil(uv.y),0);

    // Output to screen
    fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
```

The `ceil()` function allows us to see that the center of the image is 0, 0

---

As for the second part of the shadertoy documentation:

> The output color is returned in fragColor as a four-component vector,
> the last component being ignored by the client. The result is
> retrieved in an "out" variable in anticipation of the future addition
> of several rendering targets.

Really all this means is that `fragColor` contains four values that are shopped to the next stage in the rendering pipeline. [You can find more about in and out variables here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29672/in-out-keywords-in-glsl).

The values in `fragColor` determine the color of the pixel where the shader is being applied.

If you want to learn more about shaders these are some good starting places:

[the book of shader - uniform](https://thebookofshaders.com/03/?lan=en)
[learn OpenGL - shader](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders)

Comment: So, this was the thing throwing me way off... 
fragCoord.x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4...}
fragCoord.y = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4...}
iResolution = (640, 480)

Comment: Doing the math in my original question...
I get a coordinate system that goes from (-7.1, -4) to (7.1, 4).. 
Yes? No? haha

Comment: The thing that was throwing me off was the 'swizzling'.  https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Vectors
iResolution.xy will give you a vec2, but just dividing by iResolution will give you incompatible types.  iResolution (without .xy) is not a vec2

Comment: "These coordinates are counted in pixels with values from 0.5 to resolution-0.5". Doesn't that mean that there should be an offset, i.e. gl_FragCoord.xy - 0.5F, for all the examples to be correct?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Not to take away from the accepted answer, which is very thorough.  But in case anyone else was confused about the types, iResolution is a 'uniform highp 3-component vector of float'... so actually a vec3?  That's why we see in examples that fragCoord (actually a vec2) is divided by iResolution.xy (the .xy gives us a vec2).  But what is the '.xy' thing?  Is it a method?  An attribute or property?  With some random googling I found out that the '.xy' tacked on at the end is called 'swizzling'

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Vectors

(for convenience the gist of it is here below)

**Swizzling**

You can access the components of vectors using the following syntax:

```
vec4 someVec;
someVec.x + someVec.y;
This is called swizzling. You can use x, y, z, or w, referring to the 
first, second, third, and fourth components, respectively.
```

The reason it has that name "swizzling" is because the following syntax is entirely valid:

```
vec2 someVec;
vec4 otherVec = someVec.xyxx;
vec3 thirdVec = otherVec.zyy;
```

You can use any combination of up to 4 of the letters to create a vector (of the same basic type) of that length. So otherVec.zyy is a vec3, which is how we can initialize a vec3 value with it. Any combination of up to 4 letters is acceptable, so long as the source vector actually has those components. Attempting to access the 'w' component of a vec3 for example is a compile-time error.

Swizzling also works on l-values (left values?):

```
vec4 someVec;
someVec.wzyx = vec4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0); // Reverses the order.
someVec.zx = vec2(3.0, 5.0); // Sets the 3rd component of someVec to 3.0 and the 1st component to 5.0
```

However, when you use a swizzle as a way of setting component values, you cannot use the same swizzle component twice. So someVec.xx = vec2(4.0, 4.0); is not allowed.

Additionally, there are 3 sets of swizzle masks. You can use xyzw, rgba (for colors), or stpq (for texture coordinates). These three sets have no actual difference; they're just syntactic sugar. You cannot combine names from different sets in a single swizzle operation. So ".xrs" is not a valid swizzle mask.

In OpenGL 4.2 or ARB_shading_language_420pack, scalars can be swizzled as well. They obviously only have one source component, but it is legal to do this:

```
float aFloat;
vec4 someVec = aFloat.xxxx;
```

Comment: a very usefull answer ! will edit my responce to let people know to look out for your.
Did not think that swizzling can be a hard thing to take in accout will writing the answer !

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
// -1 to 1
vec2 uv = (2.0 * fragCoord - iResolution.xy) / iResolution.xy;

vec3 col = vec3(uv.x, uv.y, 0.0);

fragColor = vec4(col1, 1.0);
```